# hide a div within the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that I call from another page (index.php), inside this div, there is another div that I dont want to show when the parent is called.

This is the HTML:

```
   <div id="loginmain">
<div id="logintitle"><b>&nbsp; Log in:</b></div>
<div id="loginbox">
    <form method="post" id="loginform" action="" name="loginform">
        <label for="username"> Username:</label><span id="asterix">*</span> <input id="username" type="text" name="username" required> <br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><span id="asterix">*</span> <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required><br><br>
        <div id="submit_login"> <input type="submit" value="Log in"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="loginfooter"><span id="newmember"><b>New to our website? Click <u>here</u></b></span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

And this is how I call it with jQuery in another page!

```
    function showLogin(){
        document.getElementById('successful').style.display="none";
        $("#login").load("index.php #loginmain");
        $("#login").css("display","block");
        $("index.php #loginfooter").css("display","none");
    }
```

The script shows the #login content correctly, but the #loginfooter is shown.

Comment: $("index.php #loginfooter").css("display","none"); This isn't a valid selector. Try removing "index.php" and just use "#loginfooter"

Comment: A note, you html code is not wellformed. You have a not matching `</div>` the line after the `#submit_login`,  because of this the form will be closed there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but try changing

```
$("index.php #loginfooter").css("display","none");
```

to

```
$("#loginfooter").hide();
```

Comment: Hopefully there is no other `#loginfooter` on the page :)

Comment: @BalintBako You mean on the parent page? That would be a violation anyway.

Comment: I'm aware of that, however he is loading elements with IDs form another page... anything can happen there.

Comment: That unfortunately had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `index.php` as a jQuery selector. In your example I think it'll work just using `$('#loginfooter')`

Comment: I assume the javascript code is in the same page as the html (you can't access other pages' elements with jQuery)

Comment: I was able to access the parent div. and it displays correctly, the only concern is to remove the footer from that div.

Comment: If you can access the parent, you should be able to access the footer. Make sure you didn't misspell the selector, and that there is no other selector with the same id

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks as if you're incorrectly nesting your elements.  You have `<div id="loginbox">` opening before `<form>`, but they're closed in the wrong order.  That might end up messing with javascript stuff.

As for the jQuery, just try `$("#loginfooter").hide();`

Comment: I changed that, but no effect nevertheless !